# Converting Python notebook to PDF using nbconvert

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, file-conversion, oserror

I am trying to convert my python notebook to pdf using:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

import os
os.chdir("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/")

!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf Project_2.ipynb
```

I am using Google colabs notebooks, https://colab.research.google.com/. But I am getting this error while conversion:

**Error:**

> OSError: xelatex not found on PATH, if you have not installed xelatex you may need to do so. Find further instructions at https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex.

How can I install Miktex on Google colabs or any way to resolve it?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to install other required packages to unlock the full capabilities of `nbconvert`:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

import os
os.chdir("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/")

!apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-plain-generic

!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf Project_2.ipynb
```

More info can be found [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-nbconvert). There are other packages that may be needed, you can find those too at the linked documentation.